# Seconds between now and timestring in a timezone

Tags: java, jodatime

My problem is that I am given a time string in the format HH:mm:ss. I know that time string will always be in PST. I need to find out the number of seconds between now and when that time would occur assuming it's today.

Here is what I have so far using Joda-Time.

```
public static DateTime formatTimeString(String time, String format) {
      DateTime now = new DateTime(getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
      now = now.withTime(LocalTime.parse(time, DateTimeFormat.forPattern(format)));
      return now;
   }

public static double timeDistance(DateTime from, DateTime to) {
    return Seconds.secondsBetween(from.toInstant(), to.toInstant()).getSeconds();
}

public static DateTime currentTime() {
    return new DateTime(getTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles"));
}

private static DateTimeZone getTimeZone(String timezone) {
    return DateTimeZone.forID(timezone);
}
```

If I call:

```
timeDistance(formatTimeString("16:15:00", "HH:mm:ss"), currentTime());
```

it doesn't work as expected. It will correctly spit out the date for the formatted string as today but with the time being 16:15:00 -7 (because it is in pacific time). The current time though is being returned as UTC even though I explicitly ask for it in PST. Therefore my distance is being returned incorrectly.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you provide results of the incorrect behaviour? I ran your code for a couple of samples of "current time" and it looked OK.

Comment: BTW - in `timeDistance` you don't need the `.toInstant()` calls - `DateTime` is already a `ReadableInstant`. And since `getSeconds()` returns an `int`, I would keep it as a return type instead of `double`. But none of that should affect the results.